# Check lebesgue integrable or not...

Tags: continuity, lebesgue-integral

Consider the given question:

Let
\begin{align}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x, &\text{if} \ x\in [0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}, \\
x^2, &\text{if} \ x\in[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then

(a) $f$ is Riemann integrable and Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$

(b) $f$ is Riemann integrable but not Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$

(c) $f$ is not Riemann integrable but Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$

(d) $f$ is neither Riemann integrable nor Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$

Clearly the function is not Riemann integrable, being continuous at only two points i.e. $0$ and $1$.. But is  there a way to check whether it is Lebesgue integrable or not...

Comment: what have you tried? What are basic facts about arithmetic of measurable functions?

Comment: **Hint** $f(x)=x^2\boldsymbol 1_{[0,1]}(x)$ a.e.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is Lebesgue integrable. Since $f$ is bounded, we only need to show $f$ is measurable. For any $a\in[0,1]$,
$$f^{-1}[-\infty,a)=\big(\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,a)\big)\cup\big((\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})\cap[0,\sqrt a)\big).$$
The RHS is clearly Lebesgue measurable.